# What does double question mark mean in javascript / typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, symbols

I saw this code but did not understand what this symbole means in Javascript or typescript:

```
const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient(context);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer for lazy people like me:

If `firstValue` is **null** or **undefined**

```js
console.log(firstValue ?? secondValue) // secondValue
```

If `firstValue` isn't **null** or **undefined**

```js
console.log(firstValue ?? secondValue) // firstValue
```